# MSSMS - CSV file contains data but returns NULL with stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been trying my darndest to get the code described below to work.  I am very inexpert at MSSMS and SQL. That said, I love the efficiency of SQL databases and would really love to make this code work.

I have tested my CSV files with this code:

```
BULK INSERT BCPData
FROM 'D:\cheese\bcp_test.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
     ,ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
);
GO
```

They import easily and the data appears.

However, if I try to use the code shown below (I need an code that automatically imports multiple CSV files into my table) I only get "NULL" results in the columns.

My query is as follows:

```
 exec ImportFiles 'd:\cheese\' , 'd:\cheese\Archive' , 'bcp*.csv' , 'MergeBCPData'
```

I run this query after using the following code to create the necessary stored procedures:

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[ImportFiles]') and `OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)`
drop procedure [dbo].[ImportFiles]
GO

create procedure ImportFiles
@FilePath       varchar(1000) = 'd:\cheese\' ,
@ArchivePath        varchar(1000) = 'd:\cheese\Archive\' ,
@FileNameMask       varchar(1000) = 'bcp*.csv' ,
@MergeProc      varchar(128) = 'MergeBCPData'

AS

    set nocount on
    
declare @ImportDate datetime
    select @ImportDate = getdate()
    
declare @FileName       varchar(1000) ,
    @File           varchar(1000)

declare @cmd varchar(2000)
    
    create table ##Import (s varchar(8000))
    create table #Dir (s varchar(8000))
    
    /*****************************************************************/
    -- Import file
    /*****************************************************************/
    select  @cmd = 'dir /B ' + @FilePath + @FileNameMask
    delete #Dir
    insert #Dir exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    
    delete #Dir where s is null or s like '%not found%'
    while exists (select * from #Dir)
    begin
        select  @FileName = min(s) from #Dir
        select  @File = @FilePath + @FileName
        
        select  @cmd =      'bulk insert'
        select  @cmd = @cmd +   ' ##Import' 
        select  @cmd = @cmd +   ' from'
        select  @cmd = @cmd +   ' ''' + replace(@File,'"','') + ''''
        select  @cmd = @cmd +   ' with (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','''
        select  @cmd = @cmd +   ',ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a''
        )'
        
        truncate table ##Import
        
        -- import the data
        exec (@cmd)
                
        -- remove filename just imported
        delete  #Dir where s = @FileName
        
        exec @MergeProc
        
        
        -- Archive the file
        select @cmd = 'move ' + @FilePath + @FileName + ' ' + @ArchivePath + @FileName
        exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
    end
    
    drop table ##Import
    drop table #Dir
go



  if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[MergeBCPData]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
    drop procedure [dbo].[MergeBCPData]
    GO

create procedure MergeBCPData

AS
    set nocount on
    
    -- insert data to production table
    insert  BCPData
        (
        City ,
        Visit_Duration_Seconds ,
        Timezone ,      
        Most_Likely_Company 
        )
    select  
        SUBSTRING('City', 1, 5),
        SUBSTRING('Visit_Duration_Seconds', 1, 12),
        SUBSTRING('Timezone', 1, 3), 
        SUBSTRING('Most_Likely_Company',1, 30)  
    from    ##Import
    
go
```

Any help would be very appreciated.  I'm hopeful it is just an error that my inexperienced eyes are too novel to catch.  THANK YOU!

Comment: In your proc MergeBCPData ##Import table doenst even exist. If I have to do this I would insert first all the data from the files into a temp table and then in the same procedure insert into the production table from the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

You stated 'I need an code that automatically imports multiple CSV files into my table'.  Is there a pattern in the file names that you can exploit?  Do the file names have dates in them, per chance?  If there is some repeating pattern that you can exploit, like a series of dates, you can loop through all the files in your folder, and append all files to one table, in one go.  Check out the code below, and post back if you have questions.

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=50) – we are running 50 loops...change this as needed
BEGIN

PRINT @intFlag


declare @fullpath1 varchar(1000)
select @fullpath1 = '''\\your_path_here\FTP\' + convert(varchar, getdate()- @intFlag , 112) + '_Daily.csv'''
declare @cmd1 nvarchar(1000)
select @cmd1 = 'bulk insert [dbo].[Daily] from ' + @fullpath1 + ' with (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', FIRSTROW = 5, ROWTERMINATOR=''0x0a'')'
exec (@cmd1)


SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    
END
```

Here are some common date formats.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Again, I'm assuming you have dates in your file names.